call GetProcessesByName on Remote Machine
How do you supply the username and password credentials to the vb.net call GetProcessesByName to retrieve process information on a remote server?
Am I using the wrong call to retrieve remote server process information?
Any help is appreciated.

The ProcessStartInfo object stores that information. You haven't posted any code, though
